# Leaflet: async alternative to pointToLayer?

Tags: javascript, promise, leaflet

Right now, I have something like:

```js
this.Layer = Leaflet.geoJSON(geoJson, {
    pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
        return Leaflet.marker(latlng, {
            icon: arrowIcon,
            rotationAngle: (<MyFeatureType>feature.properties).DirectionTo,
            title: (<MyFeatureType>feature.properties).Speed.toString()
            });
        }
   }
```

This works. For each `Point` feature in the GeoJSON, my function gets called, and I get to create a custom marker.

However, I'd like to change it such as that the `pointToLayer` function is async; something like:

```js
this.Layer = Leaflet.geoJSON(geoJson, {
    pointToLayer: async function (feature, latlng) {
        var data = await retrieveSomeMetadataForFeature(feature);

        return Leaflet.marker(latlng, {
            icon: data.Icon,
            rotationAngle: (<MyFeatureType>feature.properties).DirectionTo,
            title: (<MyFeatureType>feature.properties).Speed.toString()
            });
        }
   }
```

Unfortunately, Leaflet doesn't seem to support handling a Promise as a return type.

*Nor*, it seems, can I simply return `null` and add the marker manually, e.g.:

```js
this.Layer = Leaflet.geoJSON(geoJson, {
    pointToLayer: async function (feature, latlng) {
        var data = await retrieveSomeMetadataForFeature(feature);

        var marker = Leaflet.marker(latlng, {
            icon: data.Icon,
            rotationAngle: (<MyFeatureType>feature.properties).DirectionTo,
            title: (<MyFeatureType>feature.properties).Speed.toString()
            });
        }

        // manually add marker to layer here

        return null; // simply tell Leaflet that this has been handled
   }
```

While the marker appears, Leaflet never calls into `pointToLayer` a second time.

Questions:

- is there a way to call `pointToLayer` and return the result asynchronously to Leaflet? (Presumably, all that would accomplish is add the marker to the correct layer group?)
- failing that, can I somehow tell Leaflet not to create the marker at all, and that the "event" of sorts has been handled?
- or, is there an alternative to `pointToLayer` that overrides marker creation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Return an empty `LayerGroup` per point feature, then later fill said `LayerGroup` with whatever `Marker` you need, e.g.

```
L.geoJSON(geoJson, {
    pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
        var emptyGroup = L.layerGroup();

        retrieveSomeMetadataForFeature(feature).then(function(metadata){
            L.marker(icon: metadata.icon).addTo(emptyGroup);
        });

        return emptyGroup;
   }
});
```

This way, the `pointToLayer` callback will always return an instance of `L.Layer`, as `L.GeoJSON` is expecting. The `L.GeoJSON` instance will contain several instances of `L.LayerGroup`, each containing an instance of `L.Marker`, but the overhead shouldn't be big enough to be a concern.

Comment: Yes! I think that’s what I’m looking for. Let me try.